# Plotting for various parameter values with single code

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot for four different values of a parameter with the following code

```
axisFlip = # /. {x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> 
  MapAt[#~Reverse~2 &, x, 1], 
 x : ((PlotRange | FrameTicks) -> _) :> x~Reverse~2} &;
c = 0.1;
ω = -1.99;
v = -2.5;
y = 0.05;
s = v (1 + y);
q = v (1 - y);
a = 0;
ν = s - ω + ((
P*(1 - 2 δ*Cos[c] + δ^2))/(1 + 
  a*P *(1 - 2 δ*Cos[c] + δ^2)));
δ = q - ω + (P/(1 + a*P)) ;
LogLogPlot[{P Abs[(
1 + (ν - E^(I c)) (E^(I c) - δ))/(E^(I c) - 
  E^(-I c))]^2}, {P, 10^-2, 10^1}, PlotRange -> {10^-1, 10^2}, 
PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 350, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
FrameTicks -> {{{10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0, 10^1}, 
None}, {{10^-1, 10^0, 10^1, 10^2}, None}}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12]]
```

and

```
a1 = LogLogPlot[{P Abs[(
  1 + (ν - E^(I c)) (E^(I c) - δ))/(E^(I c) - 
    E^(-I c))]^2}, {P, 1/10^2, 10^1}, 
PlotStyle -> 
Directive[RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], AbsoluteThickness[1.48], Dashed], 
PlotRange -> {1/10, 10^2}, PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 350, 
Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12]] // axisFlip
```

Then in the same plot I want to add another variation in which I have to redefine $\nu$ and $\delta$ separately like

```
ν = q - ω + ((
P*(1 - 2 δ*Cos[c] + δ^2))/(1 + 
  a*P *(1 - 2 δ*Cos[c] + δ^2)));
δ = s - ω + (P/(1 + a*P)) ;
```

re-do the above process, generate another plot `a2` with other parameters as before and then use `g = Show[a1, a2]` to get the desired output.

[image]

Is there a way to generate the output with a single code? Secondly, the Frame ticks are strange they should be $10^{-1},10^0,10^1,10^2$ on x-axis and $10^{-2},10^{-1},10^0,10^1$ on y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as good practice, limit the scope of your reclarations using [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html). Do not declare the variables you want to change, but use [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) to replace the variables with the intended value. Also, use indentation to make your code readable.

```
axisFlip = # /. {x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> MapAt[#~Reverse~2 &, x, 1], 
     x : ((PlotRange | FrameTicks) -> _) :> x~Reverse~2} &;
With[
 {c = 0.1, ω = -1.99, v = -2.5, y = 0.05, a = 0},
 With[
  {s = v (1 + y), q = v (1 - y)},
  LogLogPlot[
    Evaluate@ReplaceRepeated[
      P Abs[(1 + (ν - E^(I c)) (E^(I c) - δ))/(E^(I c) - E^(-I c))]^2
      , {
       {
        ν -> s - ω + ((P*(1 - 2 δ*Cos[c] + δ^2))/(1 + a*P*(1 - 2 δ*Cos[c] + δ^2))),
        δ -> q - ω + (P/(1 + a*P))
        },
       {
        ν -> q - ω + ((P*(1 - 2 δ*Cos[c] + δ^2))/(1 + a*P*(1 - 2 δ*Cos[c] + δ^2))),
        δ -> s - ω + (P/(1 + a*P))
        }
       }
      ]
    , {P, 0.009, 11.}
    , AspectRatio -> 1
    , PlotRange -> {0.1, 2 100}
    , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
    , PlotStyle -> {Black, Directive[Black, Dashed]}
    , ImageSize -> 350
    , FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12]
    , FrameTicks -> {{PowerRange[10^-2, 10^2], 
       None}, {PowerRange[10^-2, 10^2], None}}
    ] // axisFlip
  ]]
```

[image]